# How do I catch the onclose (onbeforeunload) event of a child window in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have tried to make a function in Vue.js, that open a new window in Chrome. I need to capture the onclose or onbeforeunload event of the window from the same component in Vue that opened the window. I try to implement it in this way:

```
...
methods: {
    gitConnet(){
            var child = window.open("https://www.google.it", '_blank', 'fullscreen=no,height=600,width=800,top=100,location=no,titlebar=0');

            child.onclose = function(){ console.log('Child window onclose closed'); };

            child.onbeforeunload = function(){ console.log('Child window onbeforeunload closed'); };
        }
}
...
```

With this code I'm able to open the new window, but when I close the window, I don't see any message in the console. I have also tried to insert the child variable in the data property of the component, but nothing is changed.

Please, someone could help me to catch the onclose event of the window inside the Vue component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My understanding of Vue is that it uses a virtual DOM and this may not be present in a new window that is launched.  You might consider a modal or child component on the same page as you load your app and then detect when it is closed or unloaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that can not be done that way.

However, something like this may get you close enough to what you are after.

```
...
methods: {
  gitConnet(){
    var child = window.open("https://www.google.it", '_blank', 'fullscreen=no,height=600,width=800,top=100,location=no,titlebar=0');

    var loop = setInterval(function() {   
      if(child.closed) {
        clearInterval(loop);
        alert('closed');

        // Do your thing here it has been closed.

      }
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

...

Simplified example: https://jsfiddle.net/v3qkswd2/